# How can I prevent spring-security from appending ;jsessionid=XXX to login redirects?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, spring-security, jetty

When an unauthenticated client requests a URL that requires a non-anonymous access level as defined in `security-config.xml`, spring security sends an HTTP redirect to our login page (e.g. `/login`).  That's fine.

The issue is that absent an existing session (identified by a cookie provided in the client's request), spring-security issues a redirect that also specifies the client's new session in the URL, e.g. `/login;jsessionid=8o7pglapojus`.

Many containers support this (apparently it works fine in tomcat?), but it appears that Jetty (which is what we're using right now) does not -- the redirected URL comes through to our URL router completely intact (including the `jsessionid` "parameter"), and the named session is not associated with the `/login` request by jetty/spring-security (i.e. a totally new session ID is provided in the Set-Cookie header of the response to the `/login` request).

We can work around this by matching `/login.*` in our routes, but I'm curious if there's any way to prevent the emission of the session id in the authentication redirect to begin with.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Spring Security 3.0.0 M1 or newer you could set `disable-url-rewriting="true"` in the `<http>` namespace. See if that helps. Also see this [feature request](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1052).

Comment: @BalusC any known pre-spring 3 solution?

Comment: @Xorty Take a look at http://fralef.org/tomcat-disable-jsessionid-in-url.html, if upgrading to Spring Security 3+ isn't an option.

Answer (score 8):

Now it looks like this.

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
```

After this, your application will be unable to perform stateful jobs properly.

Comment: You mean if the client does not permit cookies, only then the application will not be able to perform state ful jobs ?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is here (for those Spring Security at all i.e. myself)

[http://randomcoder.com/articles/jsessionid-considered-harmful](https://randomcoder.org/articles/jsessionid-considered-harmful)

Creates a Servlet filter wrapper  and manages handles this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jetty, simply add the following context-param tag in your web.xml,

```
<!-- Disables appending JSESSSIONID in browser address bar/requests -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionIdPathParameterName</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Refer: [Session Management - Jetty Doc](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/session-management.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved this issue...

the scenario was I had a few session less and security="none" pages and upon re-direct post submission - redirect url used to get appended with ;Jsessionid= in url - ofcourse leading to errors...

Also, i couldn't add disable-url-rewriting="true" also didn't work.

What worked for me if below code in submission on form-submission

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if (session != null) session.invalidate();
```

this made sure there is no active session - which ensures spring on redirect post submission doesn't need to carry session information, hence no need to add JSESSION to the url.

This was of course needed my specific case.. and cannot be used as generic solution for the whole application. Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

@ahmet alp balkan:

seamframework provide a better solution than randomcoders.
http://seamframework.org/Documentation/RemovingJSESSIONIDFromYourURLsAndFixingScache

@BalusC:

If developer used spring security's FilterChainProxy to implement the securtiy feature,just not using http namespace.

Then we couldn't find a way to add disable-url-rewriting without try to add a custom filter to filter chain,or insert a independent filter to web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I already added an answer to this for specific use cases - here are multiple ways you can tackle it (summarizing my discovery journey and experiments)

1. @ overall level - ensures no url rewriting level

> `<sec:http pattern="/<your url pattern>/**"
>   disable-url-rewriting="true"`

2. ensures no session information is not needed, hence no need to append JSESSSIONID

> `<%@ page session="false" %>`

3. @ Controller level - before directing to page/url invalidate the session. No Session > No Session Information TO Carry > No appending JSESSIONID

> `HttpSession session = request.getSession();  if (session != null)
>   session.invalidate();`

These solutions are specific to spring security. There are other solutions which can be done @ Tomcat level

1. changing session tracking to COOKIE, session information already with browser cookie > No need to pass information in url > No appending JSESSIONID 
   [doesn't work where cookies are not allowed, I faced the issue with Safari/Opera Browsers + Chrome with strict third party cookie settings]

> `<session-config>
>       <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode> </session-config>`

2. disableURLRewriting at the web server level

> In WEB-INF/web.xml `disableURLRewriting = "true"`

Hope this helps you.