# How to stop REST call pick up JSESSIONID cookie?

Tags: rest, session, cookies

I am working on a site of fairly large size. Till now, complete interactions between server and web client was managed through JSESSIONID cookie and in memory session object on application server. But now I want to move a part of my website to sateless REST APIs. For this, i have to manage REST API Access-Token as well in Cookies. Since I can not move my complete web site to REST API based architecture in one go and large part of my site will continue to use session based functionality, I can not do away with JSESSIONID cookie for quite some time. Now the problem is that JSESSIONID based Cookie will automatically be picked up in all REST API calls which I do not want as the session based Cookie in REST call will bind the call to specific application sever maintaining that session and in a sense will not let the application make use of stateless nature of REST and its distributed architecture.
Is there a way I can stop the session based Cookies getting applied to REST calls so that REST calls only pick up the Access-Token cookie and does not pick up JSESSIONID Cookie. Please note that both JSESSIONID Cookie as well Access-Token Cookie are applied to same domain and JSESSIOND cookie is applied to all the sub paths under root context path. Also all the Cookies, JSESSIONID Cookie as well as Access-Token Cookie are HttpOnly.

Comment: That default behavior, you must have used form login spring security sso, so its browser who adds cookie, just to know user is authenticated, you can add one filter which can take the cookie from URL as response, look urls carefully, there is must one url response with `JSESSIONID=your cookie`, just add filter take it, store in local-storage, add as token

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291236/how-can-i-prevent-spring-security-from-appending-jsessionid-xxx-to-login-redire